# Append Symbol Layer PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, migration, rendering

I am updating a QGIS2 plugin to QGIS3. The following code in PyQGIS2 works:

```
        association_symbol = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("ArrowLine").createSymbolLayer({
        'arrow_width': '0.4',
        'head_length': '2.0',
        'head_thickness' : '0.75',
        'color': 'red',
        'line_color': 'red',
        'is_curved': '0',
        'arrow_start_width': '.2'
    })
    self.road_object_path_association_layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].appendSymbolLayer(association_symbol)
```

I made an attempt at correcting for PyQGIS3, but it does not work:

```
        association_symbol = QgsApplication.symbolLayerRegistry().symbolLayerMetadata("ArrowLine").createSymbolLayer({
        'arrow_width': '0.4',
        'head_length': '2.0',
        'head_thickness' : '0.75',
        'color': 'red',
        'line_color': 'red',
        'is_curved': '0',
        'arrow_start_width': '.2'
    })
    self.road_object_path_association_layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayers()[0].appendSymbolLayer(association_symbol)
```

The error returned is as follows:

> AttributeError: 'QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayer' object has no attribute 'appendSymbolLayer'

The `symbols()` object required an argument.  I was not sure what argument to provide.  Further research let me to believe I could get the info from the `symbolLayers()[0]` object, but that appears to have been a red herring. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `symbolLayers()[0]` this,

```
road_object_path_association_layer.renderer().symbol()
```

is a `QgsLineSymbol` that inherits from `QgsSymbol` and here you find the method `appendSymbolLayer`

**Code**:

```
association_symbol = QgsApplication.symbolLayerRegistry().symbolLayerMetadata("ArrowLine").createSymbolLayer({
        'arrow_width': '0.4',
        'head_length': '2.0',
        'head_thickness' : '0.75',
        'color': 'red',
        'line_color': 'red',
        'is_curved': '0',
        'arrow_start_width': '.2'
    })
road_object_path_association_layer.renderer().symbol().appendSymbolLayer(association_symbol)
road_object_path_association_layer.triggerRepaint() # Add repaint layer
```

Class [Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbol.html#a4efca55cefe9b20dcb2ae94a065ec7f6)

Comment: Thanks, @Fran, for your assistance and your patience with a noob!

Comment: Your weolcome. Accept it as an answer if it solved your problem